# I was trying to Automate Testing Facebook Login and publishing a Post using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

Login is working fine but stuck at creating proper locator for textArea for writing post.

````
       {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\NITIN\\eclipse-workspace\\SeleniumDemo\\src\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
           //headless --> faster than browser mode
           WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  //WebDriver is a interface and ChromeDriver is a class which has implemented WebDriver for chrome browser.
           driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
           
           
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']")).sendKeys("nmmishra5"); 
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='pass']")).sendKeys("******"); 
           driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_b")).click();
           
       }
       public void post()
       {
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"_5xu4\"]")).click();
       }```
````

Answer (score 1):

Generally , it is not recommenced to use Facebook --

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/gmail_email_and_facebook_logins/

If you are looking for websites to practice you can find handful here,

https://www.techbeamers.com/websites-to-practice-selenium-webdriver-online/

or just google -selenium code practise websites

Comment: Oh is it so... i am a beginner ,i was not familiar with that. Thanks for the resources.